# Could someone explain to me what the following Java code is doing?

Tags: java, binary, hex, bit-manipulation

```
byte s[] = getByteArray()
for(.....)
Integer.toHexString((0x000000ff & s[i]) | 0xffffff00).substring(6);
```

I understand that you are trying to convert the byte into hex string. What I don't understand is how that is done. For instance if s[i] was 00000001 (decimal 1) than could you please explain:

1. Why 0x000000ff & 00000001 ? Why not directly use 00000001?
2. Why result from #1 | 0xffffff00?
3. Finally why substring(6) is applied?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's basically because bytes are signed in Java. If you promote a byte to an int, it will sign extend, meaning that the byte `0xf2` will become `0xfffffff2`. Sign extension is a method to keep the value the same when widening it, by copying the most significant (sign) bit into all the higher-order bits. Both those values above are `-14` in two's complement notation. If instead you had widened `0xf2` to `0x000000f2`, it would be `242`, probably *not* what you want.

So the `&` operation is to strip off any of those extended bits, leaving only the least significant 8 bits. However, since you're going to be forcing those bits to 1 in the next step anyway, this step seems a bit of a waste.

The `|` operation following that will force all those upper bits to be 1 so that you're guaranteed to get an 8-character string from `ffffff00` through `ffffffff` inclusive (since `toHexString` doesn't give you leading zeroes, it would translate `7` into `"7"` rather than the `"07"` that you want).

The `substring(6)` is then applied so that you only get the last two of those eight hex digits.

It seems a very convoluted way of ensuring you get a two-character hex string to me when you can just use `String.format ("%02x", s[i])`. However, it's possible that this particular snippet of code may predate Java 5 when `String.format` was introduced.

---

If you run the following program:

```
public class testprog {
    public static void compare (String s1, String s2) {
        if (!s1.equals(s2))
            System.out.println ("Different: " + s1 + " " + s2);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        byte b = -128;
        while (b < 127) {
            compare (
                Integer.toHexString((0x000000ff & b) | 0xffffff00).substring(6),
                String.format("%02x", b, args));
            b++;
        }
        compare (
            Integer.toHexString((0x000000ff & b) | 0xffffff00).substring(6),
            String.format("%02x", b, args));
        System.out.println ("Done");
    }
}
```

you'll see that the two expressions are identical - it just spits out `Done` since the two expressions produce the same result in all cases.

Comment: Seems you could remove the ` | 0xffffff00).substring(6)` bit without any change in functionality.

Comment: Not quite, @Cameron, that would give a 1-character string for the range 0..15 - the code in the question always gives you two characters.

Comment: Ah yes, toHexString doesn't pad. Formatter.format might be a better approach.