# Understanding Hex number to Decimal in two compliment - Java

Tags: java, hex, type-conversion, byte, twos-complement

I am trying to understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4120818/668650) answer here.

How do both these `0xf2` and `0xfffffff2` values represent `-14`? Can you elaborate with the conversion process?

I know what is Two's complement, though.

Comment: *two*'s complement, not Tow's complement...

Comment: Note that `0xf2 == -14` *only* if your word size is 8 bits, and similarly, `0xfffffff2 == -14` *only* for a 32 bit word size; in addition to the requirement for using twos-complement representation.

Comment: In Java, 0xf2 does _not_ represent -14. 0xf2 is not a `byte` constant; an `int` constant, which will have the value 242. Try compiling `byte b = 0xf2;` and you'll get an error.

Comment: Perfectly explained here [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), i remember it this way: Read a two's complement like a regular binary number, but instead of adding subtract the value of the highest bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
0xf2 = 11110010
```

The **first bit is sign-bit**. So sign is minus. To get actual value, take 2's compliment.

```
11110010 -> 1's complement -> 00001101 -> Add 1 -> 00001110 = -14
```

Similarly, take `0xfffff...f2`. **Sign bit at the beginning.** Take 2's complement.

```
1111-1111-1111.....0010 -> 1's complement -> 00000000000...1101 -> Add 1 -> 0000...1110 -> -14
```

---

Any number of preceding `1111...` **wouldn't make a difference** to the value of a negative signed number, just as `0000..` wouldn't for positive values.

---

The above calculation is for `8-bit signed 0xf2` against `32-bit signed 0xfffffff2` which are both **mathematically equal**.

Comment: In Java 0xf2 is a (32-bit) `int` value, not an 8-bit byte. If you try `byte b = 0xf2;`, you'll get a compilation error.

Comment: @TedHopp This isn't in the Java perspective, but in general. I understand, there is 32-bit granularity with most programming languages, so it wouldn't be a -ve number at all.

Comment: With 32-bit granularity, `0xf2 === 0x000000f2.` (32-bits). But when you compare 8-bit `0xf2` against 32-bit `0xfffffff2`, they are exactly equal.

Comment: @KevinRave - According to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1): _"An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1)._" When you initialize a `byte` variable with an `int` literal, the compiler will try to down-cast the value automatically. However, it will complain if the value doesn't fit. Since 0xf2 (an `int` value of 242 base 10) doesn't fit in a `byte`, you get an error. You need to explicitly cast it: `byte b = (byte) 0xf2;`.

Answer (score 2):

In binary numbers, when using two's complement, negative values have the most significant bit set to 1.  Which bit it is, that depends on how many bit number it is.

`0xf2` interpreted as 8-bit signed value is -14, while `0xfffffff2` interpreted as 32-bit signed value is same -14.

32-bit `0x000000f2` would be 242, same as *unsigned* 8-bit `0xf2` (note: Java does not have any unsigned integer types).

Comment: Actually, in Java 0xf2 is 32-bit 242.

Comment: @TedHopp Yeah, AFAIK Java does not have byte literals at all, I'll edit the answer to be more clear.

Comment: @TedHopp Can you point me an article to read more about this 'Granularity' please?

Comment: @KevinRave - Well, "granularity" is not my terminology. In my previous comment to @Cthulhu's answer I linked to the Java Language Specification section that specifies that in Java, integer literals that don't have an "L" (in upper or lower case) at the end are `int` values. That section then links to section 4.2.1, which descibes `int` as ranging from -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive. That's the range of a 32-bit representation. The Java Virtual Machine Specification also says that `int` values are 32-bit, signed, two's-complement values.

Comment: @KevinRave - In the post you referenced in your question, it described "the byte 0xf2". This indicates a `byte` (8-bit) primitive that happens to have the hex value 0xf2. My only point is that `0xf2` _as a Java literal_ is _not_ a `byte` value but an `int` value. It's basically a cautionary warning that you can't use 0xf2 (or anything above 0x7f) to initialize a `byte` variable without explicitly casting it to a `byte`.

Comment: @TedHopp. Just a quick questions. I understand unsigned `F2` is `242`.  But since Java has all signed, shouldn't this be 114 (leaving the most significant bit aka sign bit)? and Actually -114?

Comment: @KevinRave it's two's complement... `0xF2` = `11110010` bin. Negating that, ie. taking two's complement of that is `00001101` bin + 1 = `00001110` bin = 14.

Comment: @KevinRave - As an `int` literal, 0xf2 is short for 0x000000f2 (a 32-bit value). The sign bit is not set. As an 8-bit value, hyde covered this in his last comment.

Comment: So when we say `x = F2`, then `x` actually has Two's complimented value?

Comment: @KevinRave There are two different things here. One being the width of the field (8 v/s 32 bits) and other being whether it is signed or unsigned. 0xF2 in an 8-bit field is -14 when signed, and 242 when unsigned. 32-bit 0xF2 (equivalent to 0x000000F2) is 242 always(signed/unsigned). 0xFFFFFFF2 in a 32-bit field is -14 when signed and +4294967282 when unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

> How do both these 0xf2 and 0xfffffff2 values represent -14?

They don't.

```
int a = 0xf2;
int b = 0xfffffff2;
```

are different values. The only case where they represent the same number is:

```
byte a = (byte)0xf2;
byte b = 0xfffffff2;
```

and that's because of sign extension when the byte is *used* in an integer context. Note that

```
byte a = 0xf2;
```

doesn't even compile, so it's hard to see what your question is really about.